# Integer Solutions to Equation

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find the integer solutions to $x^2+xy+y^2=x^2y^2$

I have tried doing a modulo 2 analysis, which only says that $x, y$ are congruent modulo 2. But I cannot continue from here.

Answer (score 3):

Of course we have the trivial solution $x=y=0$. Forget about that and assume $x \neq 0 \neq y$.

The equation is equivalent to $(x+y)^2=(xy)^2+xy$. In particular the RHS is a square other than $(xy)^2$. Let us consider two cases:

1. $xy > 0$. Then $(xy)^2+xy$ is at least the next square, so we obtain $(xy)^2+xy \geq (xy+1)^2 = (xy)^2+2xy+1$, contradiction!
2. $xy < 0$. Then $(xy)^2+xy$ is at most the previous square, we obtain $(xy)^2+xy \leq (xy+1)^2 = (xy)^2+2xy+1$ (the previous square is obtained with $+1$, since $xy$ is negative!), hence $xy \geq -1$. So $(x,y)=(1,-1)$ or $(-1,1)$ are the only non-trivial solutions.

Comment: There is a another easy argument: The equation is equivalent to $$xy=(x+y+xy)(x+y-xy)$$. If $x+y \neq 0$, one of the factors of the RHS has a greater absolute value than $|xy|$. This is a contradiction, when $xy \neq 0$. So we get $x+y=0$ and from there it is easy to see $x = \pm 1, y = \mp 1$.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite 
\begin{align}
(x+y)^2&=xy(xy+1)\\
&=k(k+1)\\
\end{align}
for some $k$. Now $k$ is either even or odd. if it is even then $2q(2q+1)$ clearly can not be a square (non zero), the same holds when k is even. Therefore $xy$ can not be even and it cannot be odd, therefore it can only be zero. starting with $xy+1$ we see that it can only be zero. therefore either $xy=0$ or $xy=-1$. If $xy=0$ then we have to have $x=0, y=0$. but if $xy=-1$ then $x=1,y=-1$ or $x=-1,y=1$.

Comment: Or you can multiply by $4$ and you get:$$(2x+2y)^2=(2xy+1)^2-1$$ which is only possible of $2x+2y=0$ and $2xy+1=1$ or $2x+2y=-1$ and $2xy+1=0$. The second is not possible with $x,y$ integers, of course.

Comment: @ ThomasAndrews this is nice! many thanks.